# An anchor tag trigger is not firing automatically in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to trigger the anchor tag to avoid browser block up when I redirect to new window. The problem is the anchor tag click event "`$('#hello').trigger('click');`" is not firing automatically.

Am I missing something ?

Please correct me what is wrong in below html code.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Mobile Browser Detective</title>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(document)
                        .ready(
                                function() {
                                var isMobile = {
                                        any: function() {
                                            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|Opera Mini|IEMobile/i);
                                        }
                                    };
                                    if(isMobile.any()){
                                        window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
                                    } else {
                                        $('#hello').prop("href","javascript:window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','mywindowtitle','toolbar=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,width=500,height=600')");
                                        $('#hello').trigger('click');                       
                                    }

                                });
            </script> 
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <a id="hello">test</a>

         <!-- Mobile Browser Detecting -->
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Only a click by the user will open a window, all browsers now prevent new windows from opening when it's not from a direct user action to avoid annoying popups.

Comment: And trigger() won't trigger the href javascript either.

Comment: I see. That's trouble. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yoi dont need to set the href attribute, you could just invoke `window.open` in the `else` block

```
if (isMobile.any()) {
} else {
    window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','mywindowtitle','toolbar=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,width=500,height=600')
}
```

Comment: I'm invoking via a href because I'd like to avoid browser pop up block,when the new window comes up. And, I need to have new re-size window.

Comment: Have you tested it and is it being blocked?

Comment: It is blocked as long as we don't allow it in browser.

Comment: seems like only chrome doesn't block it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#hello').click();
```

or :

```
window.location = $('#myanchor').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not invoke click-event of an anchor tag from javascript/jquery. This is a security measure built into the browser.

> The click method is intended to be used with INPUT elements of type
>   button, checkbox, radio, reset or submit. Gecko does not implement the
>   click method on other elements that might be expected to respond to
>   mouse–clicks such as links (A elements), nor will it necessarily fire
>   the click event of other elements.

[See Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/API/Element.click)

You can directly use [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) method for this(which one you set as into anchor "href" ):

```
window.open('http://www.yahoo.com','mywindowtitle','toolbar=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,width=500,height=600')
```

Comment: But I'd like to avoid browser block up prevention.

Comment: Ok, than you are right. The popup blockers will engage if window.open or similar is invoked from javascript that is not invoked by direct user action.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the Click event of this tag using Id and then trigger the event, When event trigger Redirect it using Window.location...